# Does Cloud9 IDE support X11 Forwarding?

Tags: cloud9-ide, x11-forwarding

I'm developing a little cross-platform 3d/game engine in C++ and I've recently discovered Cloud9, that let me code anywhere, not need to be at home! The last thing I need to have all the environment ready is to run the game, that uses X11 to create the main window.

It would be nice if I could connect to my Cloud9 workspace from outside using X11 Forwarding and Xming, but 22 port is closed and the only open port (by default) is 8080 with an HTTP proxy, so I can't open another ssh server in that port to be accessible from outside :(

[Here](https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/can-i-use-cloud9-to-do-x/) is where I've found all the info about ports and services accessible from outside.

Does anyone know if there is any way to do X11 Forwarding accessible from outside?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you get X11 forwarding to work, the performance will not be very good. Either your game is blitting whole framebuffer, in which case you're sending uncompressed images over the internet (at video rates…) or you're getting an indirect OpenGL context, which limits you to OpenGL-2.1 and before; textures are again transmitted uncompressed and geometry either must be uploaded to the server by Display Lists or by using the Vertex Buffer Object extension (which became core functionality only in OpenGL-3.0) and unless you do that every triangle you draw goes over the net.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: OpenGL over IP could be done quite efficiently (Vertex Buffer Objects and transparent texture data compression are the keys here), but so far no implementation actually supports this (Buffer Objects over IP or lossless image data compression for transmission).

Comment: I don't need speed, only see if it's working properly. I didn't know that indirect OpenGL contexts was limited to profile 2.1 and lower! I'll try x11 forwarding in my local machine before going further with Cloud9. Anyway, thank you for the info!

Comment: Just for the sake of completenes: The indirect GLX limitation to OpenGL-2.1 and lower is not due to technical reasons, but because nobody bothered to update the GLX specifications. A GLX3 really should be specified IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid this is not possible. Currently only the 8080 http proxy port is exposed to the outside world. However, you can use Cloud9 with another remote machine, e.g. one from digitalocean.com. See also https://docs.c9.io/run_your_own_workspace.html.